# Using Char Array Reference In Loop In C

Tags: c, string, pointers, arrays

If I have a char array in C I am using it in a loop:

```
char arr [100];
while (1) {
    fill arr from some source
    store arr in some where
}
```

Now, with this approach, I loose all the subsequent arrays, I maintain a pointer to the last one only. How can I maintain that?

Please don't suggest using strings to me :)

Answer (score 2):

Use an alternate array to store previous strings:

```
char arr [100];
char* arrOfStrings[100];

int i = 0;
while (1) {
    //fill arr
    arrOfStrings[i] = malloc(strlen(arr)+1);
    strncpy(arrOfStrings[i], arr, strlen(arr));
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `strcpy()` to make copies.

```
char arr[100];
while(1) {
    /* fill arr */
    char *str = malloc(strlen(arr) + 1);
    strcpy(str, arr);
    /* store str in some where */
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this solves the problem that previous strings are lost. `str` is declared inside the loop, so outside of it it would be lost. See my answer.

Comment: I made a typo and have fixed. It is `str` which should be stored somewhere, not `arr`.

Comment: -1 for teaching to cast the result of malloc in C. Read [this](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use linked lists, since you don't know the number of lines you want to store:

```
char arr[100];
struct listOfLines
{
    char *line;
    struct listOfLines *next;
};

struct listOfLines *myListOfLines = NULL;
struct listOfLines *tempLine = NULL;
while(1)
{
    /* Fill array from some source */
    myListOfLines = tempLine;
    tempLine = malloc(sizeof(struct listOfLines));
    tempLine->line = strdup(arr);
    tempLine->next = NULL;
}
```